# Downloading Yahoo stock prices in R

Tags: r, finance

This is a newbie question in R. I am downloading yahoo finance monthly stock price data  using R where the ticker names are read from a text file. I am using a loop to read the ticker names to download the data  and putting them in a list. My problem is some ticker names may not be correct thus my code stops when it encounters this case. I want the following.

1. skip the ticker name if it is not correct.
2. Each element in the list is a dataframe. I want the ticker names to be appended to variable names in element dataframes.
3. I need an efficient way to create a dataframe that has the closing prices as variables.

Here is the sample code for the simplified version of my problem.

```
library(tseries)  
tckk <- c("MSFT", "C", "VIA/B", "MMM") # ticker names defined  
numtk <- length(tckk);  
ustart <- "2000-12-30";
uend <- "2007-12-30" # start and end date  
all_dat <- list(); # empty list to fill in the data  
for(i in 1:numtk)  
{  
  all_dat[[i]] <- xxx <- get.hist.quote(instrument = tckk[i], start=ustart, end=uend, quote = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close"), provider = "yahoo", compression = "m")  
}
```

The code stops at the third entry but I want to skip this ticker and move on to "MMM". I have heard about Trycatch() function but do not know how to use it.

As per question 2, I want the variable names for the first element of the list to be "MSFTopen", "MSFThigh", "MSFTlow", and "MSFTclose". Is there a better to way to do it apart from using a combination of loop and paste() function.

Finally, for question 3, I need a dataframe with three columns corresponding to closing prices. Again, I am trying to avoid a loop here.

Thank you.

Comment: indent initial lines of code with 4 spaces to create a readable code block.

Comment: Minor grammar corrections.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your best bet is to use quantmod and store the results as a time series (in this case, it will be `xts`):

```
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)
symbols <- c("MSFT","C","VIA/B","MMM")

#1
l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym))) 
symbols <- symbols[symbols %in% ls()]

#2
sym.list <- llply(symbols, get) 

#3
data <- xts()
for(i in seq_along(symbols)) {
    symbol <- symbols[i]
    data <- merge(data, get(symbol)[,paste(symbol, "Close", sep=".")])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works. However, originally I am reading the ticker names from a file that has more than 1000 tickers. So hard coding with the merge() may not help me. Moreover, I do want to put them in a list so that I can use plyr library to do other stuff to each list element.

Comment: Ok, well it's easy to do both of those things.  Just loop over the symbols to merge them (rather than hard coding them).  And store then in a list with plyr: `llply(symbol.names, get)`.

Comment: One note: I much prefer `auto.assign=FALSE` in `getSymbols()` as it avoids the insanity of filling the environment with all those symbols when all I want is the merged `data.frame`.

Comment: You could further clean up the merge with: `merge(data, Cl(get(symbol)))`

Comment: @Shane I've just added "library(plyr)", as this is required (like quantmod) on a fresh installation of R.

Comment: With the latest version of quantmod, the line "l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym)))" fails sometimes (perhaps due to internal multithreading breaking the HTTP fetch?), replacing with "getSymbols(symbols)" will fix any unstability.

Comment: Building on the suggestion from @Joshua Ulrich, if you prefer the adjusted close, use "merge(data, Ad(get(symbol)))".

Comment: `l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym)))`
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=VIA/B&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=6&e=11&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=VIA/B&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=VIA/B&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=6&e=11&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=VIA/B&x=.csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Answer (score 20):

This also a little late...If you want to grab data with just R's base functions without dealing with any add-on packages, just use the function `read.csv(URL)`, where the URL is a string pointing to the right place at Yahoo.  The data will be pulled in as a dataframe, and you will need to convert the 'Date' from a string to a Date type in order for any plots to look nice.  Simple code snippet is below.

```
URL <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY"
dat <- read.csv(URL)
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Using R's base functions may give you more control over the data manipulation.

Comment: +1 This is a good tip. May be I am wrong but I guess it will have less flexibility to change the start date, end date, and data frequency. The URL will get more messy with that.

Comment: A few thoughts on this, you can stick all this in a utility function that constructs the URL, requests the data, and returns the data frame (there are a bunch more parameters you can send to yahoo in the url like the start date)...also since the data is in a data.frame, its pretty easy to filter and manipulate the data you don't want. Also, the 'merge' command is VERY useful in combining data frames of multiple tickers.

Comment: @stotastic There are already several functions that do what you describe (`quantmod::getSymbols`, `TTR::getYahooData`, `tseries::get.hist.quote`, `fImport::yahooImport`, etc).

Comment: All nice functions that add a simplifying layer of abstraction, but I think its important to know the basics of how these functions pull in the data... just using a 'back box' can be dangerous

Comment: Yes, it's helpful to understand how the functions work.  However, you don't need to write a similar function to understand how they're pulling data.  You can simply look at the source code... which isn't really a "black box".

Comment: I guess it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @stotasic I hope you don't mind, but I've just edited your answer to change "%m/%d/%Y" to "%Y-%m-%d", so the example code works with the latest version of the Yahoo API. And I've upvoted as its a great answer.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a little late to the party, but I think this will be very helpful to other late comers.

The `stockSymbols` function in `TTR` fetches instrument symbols from nasdaq.com, and adjusts the symbols to be compatible with Yahoo! Finance.  It currently returns ~6,500 symbols for AMEX, NYSE, and NASDAQ.  You could also take a look at the code in `stockSymbols` that adjusts tickers to be compatible with Yahoo! Finance to possibly adjust some of the tickers in your file.

*NOTE: `stockSymbols` in the version of `TTR` on CRAN is broken due to a change on nasdaq.com, but it is fixed in the R-forge version of `TTR`.*

Comment: +1 for this great tip. Just wanted to know if there is a quick way to extract ticker names for all companies registered in NYSE and save it in a column in a flat file. I tried using it but didn't know how to extract the ticker names from the output object of stockSymbols function call. Thanks.

Comment: `write.csv(stockSymbols("NYSE")$Symbol,"NYSE_symbols.txt",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I did try the stockSymbols("NYSE")$Symbol command earlier but it outputs strange things, not the ticker names. I  guess it must be due to CRAN version of TTR (I used install.packages() command to in stall TTR)

Comment: Yes, you probably have the CRAN version.  You can use `install.packages` to install the R-forge version: `install.packages("TTR",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")`.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich I installed the `R-forge` version and then got: `> write.csv( stockSymbols("NYSE")$Symbol, file="NYSE_symbols.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE ) ######
Fetching NYSE symbols... ######
Warning messages: ######
1: In write.csv(stockSymbols("NYSE")$Symbol, file = "NYSE_symbols.csv",  :
  attempt to set 'col.names' ignored ######
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  cols = 3 != length(data) = 4`

Comment: @Lao Tzu: please see `?write.csv`.  The "CSV Files" section says `write.csv` and `write.csv2` are "deliberately inflexible" and "Attempts to change ‘append’, ‘col.names’, ‘sep’, ‘dec’ or ‘qmethod’ are ignored, with a warning."

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich Thank you. Then I don't understand your comment above of `Aug 18 '10 at 19:48`.

Comment: @Lao Tzu: I probably wrote that code from memory (i.e. didn't test it) and intended to use `write.table` instead of `write.csv`.  `write.table` will respect the `col.names=FALSE` argument and there's only one column so the delimiter doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this, because I need to have the historic pricelist and a daily update file in order to run other packages:

```
library(fImport)

fecha1<-"03/01/2009"
fecha2<-"02/02/2010"

Sys.time()

y <- format(Sys.time(), "%y")    
m <- format(Sys.time(), "%m")    
d <- format(Sys.time(), "%d")
fecha3 <- paste(c(m,"/",d,"/","20",y), collapse="")

write.table(yahooSeries("GCI", from=fecha1, to=fecha2), file = "GCI.txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE, eol="\r\n", row.names = TRUE)
write.table(yahooSeries("GCI", from=fecha2, to=fecha3), file = "GCIupdate.txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE, eol="\r\n", row.names = TRUE)

GCI <- read.table("GCI.txt") 
GCI1 <- read.table("GCIupdate.txt")
GCI <- rbind(GCI1, GCI)
GCI <- unique(GCI)

write.table(GCI, file = "GCI.txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE, eol="\r\n", row.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Edited answer to add "library(fImport)", as this is required on a fresh installation of R.

Comment: this process is way to lengthy... can it be short?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified from the above solutions... (thanks Shane and Stotastic)

```
 symbols <- c("MSFT", "C", "MMM")

 # 1. retrieve data

 for(i in seq_along(symbols)) {
   URL <- paste0("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=", symbols[i])
   dat <- read.csv(URL)
   dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
   assign(paste0(symbols[i]," _data"), dat)
   dat <- NULL
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate goal is to get the data.frame of three columns of closing prices, then the new package `tidyquant` may be better suited for this.

```
library(tidyquant)

symbols <- c("MSFT", "C", "VIA/B", "MMM")

# Download data in tidy format. 
# Will remove VIA/B and warn you.
data <- tq_get(symbols)

# Ticker symbols as column names for closing prices
data %>% 
    select(.symbol, date, close) %>% 
    spread(key = .symbol, value = close)
```

This will scale to any number of stocks, so the file of 1000 tickers should work just fine!

Comment: Note that in v0.4.0, the ".symbol" column becomes "symbol".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, URL "ichart.finance.yahoo.com" is dead and not working now. As I know, Yahoo closed it and it seems it will not be opened.

Several days ago I found nice alternative (https://eodhistoricaldata.com/) with an API very similar to Yahoo Finance.

Basically, for R-script described above you just need to change this part:

```
URL <- paste0("ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=", symbols[i])
```

to this:

```
URL <- paste0("eodhistoricaldata.com/api/table.csv?s=", symbols[i])
```

Then add an API key and it will work in the same way as before. I saved a lot of time for my R-scripts on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give the [BatchGetSymbols](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BatchGetSymbols/vignettes/BatchGetSymbols-vignette.html) library a try. What I like about it over quantmod is that you can specify a time period for your data.

```r
library(BatchGetSymbols)

# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 60
last.date <- Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'daily'
# set tickers
tickers <- c('FB','MMM','PETR4.SA','abcdef')

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         freq.data = freq.data,
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                  'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()
```