# Importing 10-year history of company financials

Tags: r, quantmod

Loading financial data like income statements and balance sheets is possible using`quantmod` package:

```
library(quantmod)
getFinancials("GOOG")
viewFinancials(GOOG.f, type='BS', period='A')
```

The data is pulled from Google Finance and does not go beyond 2012.

Is there a meaningful way in R for loading 10-year history instead of 5-year?

**Edit:**

It looks like MorningStar provides 10-year data on some of the key ratios for free. For example, in case of Google, the direct link to the `csv` would be `financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=GOOG`

How would I be able to lead it in R using `read.csv()` function, and without hardcoding the stock name into the link? The code below is not correct but I suppose something of this sort:

```
ticker<-"GOOG"
read.csv(url(financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=ticker))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oposum,

I do not know a free solution, though I am aware of paid solutions to the problem you pose. 

For example, you can download the 10-year historical data via www.MorningStar.com either programmatically, or via download of an excel format data file.

_I am not affiliated with Morningstar. The 10-year data access requires a login and a paid subscription._

Comment: See related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177435/get-annual-financial-data-for-a-stock-for-many-years-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Check out http://www.r-bloggers.com/tfx-package/, tfx appear to have eight years of data. It is apparently free but I have not used it.

Comment: TrueFX appears to only provide foreign currency exchange data. It is sad that data beyond the past 5 years costs $200-250,

Comment: @Technophobe01 sound like MorningStar offers 10-year data on some ratios for free. I updated my post. Any way to automate importing that into R?

Comment: @Oposum It is not trivial to handle the format of these csv files. You could try `TickerName <- "MSFT"; TenYearSummary <- read.csv2(paste0("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=", TickerName))` but the output stored in `TenYearSummary` is not well structured and may need to be parsed further in order to obtain a nice data.frame.

Comment: @RHertel I understand that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Oposum You're welcome. I'm sorry that I couldn't be more helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you 10 years worth of data, where it exists.

```
stocks <- c("AXP", "BA", "CAT", "CSCO")

for (s in stocks) {
    names(urls) <- sprintf("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=%s", stocks)
    lst <- lapply(urls, read.csv, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip = 2)
    lst1 <- lapply(lst, `[`, -12)
    write.csv(lst1, file = "C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/files/data.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, na = "")
}
```